# Use parent coordinates in SKShader

Tags: ios, opengl-es, sprite-kit

I'm playing around with SKShader for iOS.

```
void main() {
  vec4 val = texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord);
  float len = 0.5 + 0.5 * sin(10.0 * u_time + 0.05 * (gl_FragCoord.x + gl_FragCoord.y));
  vec4 c = vec4(vec3(len), 1);
  gl_FragColor = c * val;
}
```

I want to assign this shader to sprites that are connected, and I want the effect to be smooth between the sprites. Hence I don't think that I can use v_tex_coord in the shader. I use gl_FragCoord instead.

The problem is that the sprites are children of a SKNode that can be moved. And as gl_FragCoord is in screen coordinates that movement will affect the animation.

Q: Is there any way to avoid that the sprite shaders are affected by a movement of the parent node without passing uniform data, containing the position and the zRotation of the sprite, to the shader?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rather than changing a uniform (which will recompile the shader), pass the size as a [SKAttribute](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skattribute) and update the attribute in your `SKSceneDelegate` `update` method.

For example:

```
let attributeBasedShader = SKShader(fileNamed: "UsingAttributes.fsh")
attributeBasedShader.attributes = [
    SKAttribute(name: "a_sprite_position", type: .vectorFloat2)]

let sprite = SKSpriteNode()
sprite.shader = attributeBasedShader


let spritePosition = vector_float2(Float(sprite.position.x), 
                                   Float(sprite.position.y))
sprite.setValue(SKAttributeValue(vectorFloat2: spritePosition), 
                forAttribute: "a_sprite_position")
```